# Error in replacement dictionary biopython 1.78

Tags: python

1. Calculating summary information

```
from Bio.Align import AlignInfo
summary_align = AlignInfo.SummaryInfo(alignment)
consensus = summary_align.dumb_consensus()
print(consensus)
```

2. #Position Specific Score Matrices

```
my_pssm = summary_align.pos_specific_score_matrix( consensus , chars_to_ignore=['N'])
print(my_pssm[0]["M"])
print(my_pssm)
```

```
#Substitution Matrices
replace_info = summary_align.replacement_dictionary()
print(replace_info[ ("A", "G") ])
print(replace_info[ ("G", "A") ])
print(replace_info[ ("A", "G") ]+replace_info[("G", "A")])
```

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Align\AlignInfo.py", line 198, in replacement_dictionary
    rep_dict = {(letter1, letter2): 0 for letter1 in letters for letter2 in letters}

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

In version 1.78 of biopython. They made some changes and I can't run replacement dictionary for multiple sequence alignment with clustal omega

Comment: Try cross posting here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi, I'm also seeing this issue. Did you figure it out?